# How can I find the closest flat area to the main character in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sometimes my main character gets stuck like this and if he stays in the air like this for 2-3 seconds, I want to move the main character to the nearest flat area. (The surface angle can be between 0f to 60f with a minimum 0.5f radius empty space)

How can I find the closest flat area to the main character in Unity?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Step it back a short amount in the direct it came from. Make sure to have it report in stuck locations

Comment: Sometimes there is a wall behind me or a side of me. So, I can't know the escape direction every time. I need to locate a safe flat location to transfer the player.

Comment: Normally then games pick safe spots. And teleport you to the nearest known safe spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) (or a similar method in the [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) class e.g. `spherecast`). From the [RaycastHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) get the [normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html) of the hit and assess if it's angle is suitable using [Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)