# Unity2D how to make object rotation acccording to ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

i have a ball that always move right on a infinite path. When i press space it needs to jump to the upper path according to slope (for example if the slope is 45 degrees, it should jump at an angle of 45 degrees ). How can i detect the slope to make these things?

[image]

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but see my answer here - the method is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034949/how-can-i-find-the-closest-flat-area-to-the-main-character-in-unity/73038736#73038736

Comment: Just an idea, you could use the `contact point` and `pivot` of your ball to get the direction, and bingo you could add force in the opposite direction.